# Suggestion for Second Interview Letter

Tags: interviewing

I recently had an interview online via Skype with a cruise line for the post of Tr Photographer, but received an email stating I was not selected.

I have prepared a letter below requesting a second interview.  Is this fine or do you have any other suggestions?  I'd like to contact them today.

> Dear Interviewer,
>
> This Email letter is a medium to express my gratitude for the
>   opportunity of a second interview round with your organization for the
>   post of Tr.Photographer.
>
> I received the interview results & came to know that am not selected.
>   It was disappointment for me. Yes, I was bit nervous at the time of
>   interview as I was very excited and couldn’t answer some of the
>   questions properly.
>
> I really don’t want to miss this job opportunity of a trainee
>   photographer. With my past photography experience and educational
>   qualification, I am sure that I will serve as an efficient employee to
>   your organization.
>
> If given the chance to work at your organization, then I will
>   certainly learn & grow professionally, while being able to utilize my
>   skills for the betterment of the organization, with use of my
>   dedication determination & resourcefulness.
>
> I look forward on being a part of your team in the near future. I will
>   positively await for your response, Thank you for the time you took to
>   conduct the interview and for considering me for the post with your
>   organization.
>
> Yours Sincerely,

Comment: No, please don't do this. It will make you look very immature and desperate.

Comment: You may want to remove all the personal info in the question.

Comment: This will not serve any purpose; send a short "thank you" and move on.

Answer (score 12):

The letter is fine but they made up their mind already. So far as they are concerned, that ship has sailed. Barking up the wrong tree is a waste of time. You might be better off using up your time looking for other opportunities. I suspect that the reason for their decision to decline your candidacy is more substantial than your nervousness.

One note: they made their decision and they couldn't care less that you don't want to miss this opportunity. What's important to you is not necessarily important to them.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than begging them to reconsider, which they will not do (they have certainly already given the job to someone else), ask them to keep you in mind for any future opportunities.  Try something like this:

> Dear Interviewer,
>
> Thank you very much for giving me a second interview for the post
>   of Trainee Photographer.  I was disappointed to learn that I was not
>   selected.
>
> I hope you will be willing to keep me in mind should another similar
>   position open up.  With my past photography experience and educational
>   qualification, I am sure that I could serve as an outstanding employee
>   in your organization.
>
> If given the chance to work at your organization, my dedication,
>   determination, and resourcefulness would certainly enable me to learn
>   & grow professionally, while utilizing my skills for the betterment of
>   the organization.
>
> Thank you again for the time you took to conduct the interview and for
>   considering me for the post, and I hope an
>   opportunity will arise that will allow us to work together at some
>   point in the near future.
>
> Yours Sincerely,

Be sure to replace "your organization" with the actual name of the organization.

It's not a typical response, and some will say that it comes off as pathetic / desperate, but it does let them know just how interested you are, and should the initial candidate not work out, they might just remember you and give you a call.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. The original letter was skillfully written but it came too close to giving the impression that the OP couldn't take "no" for an answer. In fact, it may be that he couldn't take "no" for an answer.